# how to update listview onBackPressed()

Tags: android

I am trying to update `ListView` when I go back to an activity which displays that `ListView`. For that I have `overridden` `onBackPressed` method of that activity. But when I go back to that activity `ListView` is not updated and old `ListView` is being displayed. So please help.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: The problem ist.. that you dont assign a new List to the adapter.. just do this.... adapter.setYourList( theNewDatat); and than make notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Put the call to notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume() instead

Comment: @DanielNugent its correct =)